# polymer not displaying html from import

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm just getting started with building web-components with polymer, and was following the tutorial.

I'm just at the start, and am adding my component to my page via a script, but my html from my template isn't being displayed.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    if(!window.Polymer){
        var poly = document.createElement('script');
        poly.src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/platform.js";
        document.head.appendChild(poly);   
    }

    var template = document.createElement('link');
    template.setAttribute("rel", "import");
    template.setAttribute("href", "http://localhost:8081/first-widget.html");


    document.body.appendChild(template);


    var widget = document.createElement('my-widget');
    document.body.appendChild(widget);

    setTimeout(function(){
        Polymer('my-widget');
    },1000);
 });
```

My widget is

```
<polymer-element name="my-widget">
    <template>
        <h1>This is from the Polymer</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

My understanding is that this should display the content of my html from the template in my `my-widget` tag. I've got the localhost:8081 serving the content of the template via CORS, so that isn't the issue, and I can see the template loaded into chrome via the element inspector. So I'm not sure why I'm not getting my content.

Is there a way I need to bootstrap polymer?

Answer (score 1):

In your widget, you need to import polymer.html and either use the noscript attribute:

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-widget" noscript>
    <template>
        <h1>This is from the Polymer</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

or register your element:

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-widget">
    <template>
        <h1>This is from the Polymer</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({});
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

More information on creating elements: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html

Comment: I've been playing with adding in the polymer.html, but as far as I can tell, that only includes a link to import the polymer.js script, which I've already included on my page. If I include the polymer.html, I get an error about using appendChild on html, which apparently is the result of loading polymer twice. https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/bgMajiu_iR4/rygd5Ftk668J. I've also tried using the polymer.html, and not loading the library in my script, but I still don't get the element populated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run your html into a server.
I'm using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server) that is very simple.

npm install http-server

Basically you navigate through to index.html file and run "http-server".

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was including the platform.js but not polymer.js
If anybody is loading polymer dynamically as I am (as we're building a widget which other people can include in their page), it seems it is best to use the `noscript` attribute as @pikanezi described, as you don't run into timing issues this way.